# How to NOT disable touchpad while typing?

Tags: keyboard, touchpad

In Elementary OS 0.4 Loki, the default behavior is to disable the touchpad while typing. However, this is undesired, especially while playing games. I want to be able to type and use the touchpad at the same time.

I checked the Settings app, and found nothing to disable this undesired functionality.

How do I *enable* the touchpad while typing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDR**
You can enable touchpad (that is disable auto-disable) with `xinput set-prop DEVICE PROP 0` where you can check for your device ID and prop ID with `xinput` and `xinput get-props DEVICE` respectively.

*Let's explain this a little bit:*
there is a new interface to do this in elementary OS 0.4 Loki `xinput`. In a terminal window you should look for your touchpad device:

```
user@machine:~$  xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
⋮
```

In my case the device id is `14`, so now you can get its properties

```
user@machine:~$ xinput list-props 14
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (154):   1
⋮
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (314):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (315):    1
⋮
```

The prop ID is `314` (and it is set to `1` that is, auto-disable is turned on) so now we can set disable this feature:

```
user@machine:~$ xinput set-prop 14 314 0
```

Comment: Very helpful, and explained very well! This ought to be in the settings app.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Synaptic Touchpad with synclient installed you can use :

```
synclient TouchpadOff=0
```

0 = enabled
1 = disabled
2 = disabled while typing

source : https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/touchpad#activerdesactiver_le_pave_tactile (french)

Comment: This might not work under elementary 0.4 Loki

Comment: Solved my day, hope that this is now a stable solution.